# How to get execution time in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need, in a plpgsql script, to get the execution time of the last query in a variable for several purposes (calculation, display and storage), so the psql `\timing` option is not what I look for because I can't manipulate the result time. Do you know if there is anything like the "get diagnostics" command, but for execution time (or work around) ?:

```
get diagnostics my_var := EXECUTION_TIME;
```

I couldn't find anything else than `row_count` and `result_oid`...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can compare `clock_timestamp()` before and after the query:

```
do $$
declare t timestamptz := clock_timestamp();
begin
 perform pg_sleep(random());
 raise notice 'time spent=%', clock_timestamp() - t;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Sample result:

> NOTICE:  time spent=00:00:00.59173

Comment: Actually I tried this but with now(), since it is the transaction time, I had the same time before and after, but with clock_timestamp() it works ! thanks